# Recursion on a haskell function with an Either return type

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am trying to build a string based on the lookup result from a Map in Haskell. This is my code so far:

```hs
import qualified Data.Map as Map

toRNA :: String -> Either Char String
toRNA [] = Right ""
toRNA (x:xs) = case getRna x of
    Nothing -> Left x
    Just rnaCode -> Right (rnaCode : toRNA xs)

getRna :: Char -> Maybe Char
getRna c = Map.lookup c rnaMap

rnaMap :: Map.Map Char Char
rnaMap =
    Map.fromList
    [ ('G', 'C')
    , ('C', 'G')
    , ('T', 'A')
    , ('A', 'U')
    ]
```

This obviously won't work as you cannot prepend `Char` to `Either Char String` in the line of code `Right (rnaCode : toRNA xs)`. How can you recursively call this function to build the correct string? For example: `toRNA "GCT"` should return `Right "CGA"`

The Left case here is my error case which returns the value of the first instance of a non-existent key in my `rnaMap`. For example: `toRNA "CXL"` should return `Left "X"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define `getRna` to use `Either` right away, `toRNA` becomes much simpler.

```
getRna :: Char -> Either Char Char
getRna c = case Map.lookup c rnaMap of
              Nothing -> Left c
              Just base -> Right base
-- getRna c = maybe (Left c) Right (Map.lookup c rnaMap),
-- using maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b to abstract
-- away the case expression.
```

`traverse` acts much like `map`: it applies `getRna` to each value in the string. If that application ever produces a `Left` value, it immediately returns that `Left` value. Otherwise, it takes the resulting list of `Right` values and turns it into a single string wrapped by `Right`, i.e., `[Right 'C', Right 'G']` becomes `Right ['C', 'G'] == Right "CG"`.

```
toRNA :: String -> Either Char String
toRNA = traverse getRna
```

(In fact, `traverse` is just the composition of `map` and `sequenceA`, the function that "inverts" the list of `Either Char Char` values to an `Either Char String` value:

```
toRna = sequenceA . map getRna
```

or

```
toRna s = sequenceA (map getRna s)
```

)

---

You can also keep your original `getRna` and simply adapt it in the definition of `toRNA`:

```
toRNA :: String -> Either Char Sting
toRNA = traverse getRna'
    where getRna' c = maybe (Left c) Right (getRna c)
```

If you like point-free definitions, you may get a kick out of

```
toRNA = traverse (flip maybe Right . Left <*> getRna)
```

since

```
flip maybe Right . Left <*> getRna
   -- f <*> g  == \x -> f x (g x)
   == \c -> (flip maybe Right . Left) c (getRna c)
   == \c -> (flip maybe Right (Left c)) (getRna c)
   == \c -> (maybe (Left c) Right) (getRna c)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using the fact that `Either` is an [functor](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/The_Functor_class):

```
toRNA :: String -> Either Char String
toRNA [] = Right ""
toRNA (x:xs) = case getRna x of
    Nothing -> Left x
    Just rnaCode -> (rnaCode:) <$> toRNA xs
```

(`<$>` is an infix synonym of `fmap`)

Answer (score 1):

Questions asking "how do I do this thing elegantly" seem to draw people in :) Here's yet another option, which doesn't redefine getRna and uses the `Applicative` rather than (merely) the `Functor` instance for `Either String`:

```hs
import Data.Maybe (maybe)

toRNA :: String -> Either Char String
toRNA [] = Right ""
toRNA (x:xs) = (:) <$> maybe (Left x) Right (getRna x) <*> toRNA xs
```

I think chepner's way is best, honestly, but I spent a minute working this out and figured I might as well post it; this `f <$> a <*> b` thing (which is essentially `f a b`, except everything involved is wrapped in an `Applicative`) shows up fairly often, especially when using parser combinators, and I find it neat.

Comment: You can still use `traverse` as well; you just need to compose `maybe` and `getRna` properly. Something like `traverse (\c -> maybe (Left c) Right (getRna c))` should suffice. Converting that traversal function to point-free form probably isn't worth the effort, as I suspect its a nightmare of `flip`s and nested composition.

Comment: Oh, it's actually not too bad: `traverse (flip maybe Right . Left <*> getRna)`. It's just nigh-unreadable, rather than unreadable :)

Comment: (It uses the trick that `(f <*> g) x == f x (g x)` to pass a character to both `getRna` and `flip maybe Right . Left`, resulting in a function that expects a `Maybe Char` value being applied to a `Maybe Char` value.)